# I have a form content like this

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem when it will create a view in phpmyadmin
like this # 1349 - `SELECT` Views contains subqueries in the `FROM` clause
my coding like this please help

```
SELECT b.ngr_tjuan, SUM (b.LFormal) AS LFormal, SUM (b.PFormal) AS PFormal, SUM (b.LFormal) + SUM (b.PFormal) AS SUMFormal,
SUM (b.LInformal) AS LInformal, SUM (b.PInformal) AS PInformal, SUM (b.LInformal) + SUM (b.PInformal) AS SUMInformal FROM
(SELECT a.ngr_tjuan,
(CASE WHEN a.sktor_pkrjaan = 'FORMAL' AND a.jk = 'L' THEN JJK ELSE 0 END) AS LFormal,
(CASE WHEN a.sktor_pkrjaan = 'FORMAL' AND a.jk = 'P' THEN JJK ELSE 0 END) AS PFormal,
(CASE WHEN a.sktor_pkrjaan = 'INFORMAL' AND a.jk = 'L' THEN JJK ELSE 0 END) AS LInformal,
(CASE WHEN a.sktor_pkrjaan = 'INFORMAL' AND a.jk = 'P' THEN JJK ELSE 0 END) US PInformal
FROM
(SELECT ngr_tjuan, COUNT (jk) AS JJK, sktor_pkrjaan, jk
FROM tbtki2
GROUP BY ngr_tjuan, sktor_pkrjaan, jk) a
WHERE a.JJK> 0) b
GROUP BY b.ngr_tjuan
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please format your sql query and explain your problem more exactly

Comment: #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: Presumably you are trying to create a VIEW from this query. MySQL is telling you that VIEWs (amongst other [limitations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html)) cannot contain subqueries. You can either rewrite your query to remove the subquery (perhaps by using a JOIN) or upgrade to MySQL 5.7.7 where this restriction is removed.

Comment: still error whether there is another way